# How can I base method return value on Subscription?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a small code sample that returns some data from api or from database, depending on with one from above contains any data.

Now I want to add another condition based on Network status. I use ReactiveNetwork library for this but I can't make it work, this is what I tried:

```
  @Override public Observable<List<Tactic>> getTactics(boolean forceRefresh) {

    Observable<List<Tactic>> diskObservable =
        disk.get().getTactics().compose(RxDataUtils.applyLog(SourceType.DISK));

    Observable<List<Tactic>> apiObservable = api.get()
        .getTactics()
        .doOnNext(tactics -> disk.get().save(tactics))
        .compose(RxDataUtils.applyLog(SourceType.API));

    Subscription connectivityStatusSubscription = new ReactiveNetwork().observeConnectivity(context)
        .compose(RxUtils.applyStandardSchedulers())
        .subscribe(connectivityStatus -> {
          isNetworkAvailable = RxDataUtils.isConnected(connectivityStatus);
          Timber.v("ConnectivityChanged: " + isNetworkAvailable);
        });

    if (isNetworkAvailable) return forceRefresh ?
        apiObservable : Observable.concat(diskObservable, apiObservable).first(
        tactics -> (tactics != null && tactics.size() > 0));
    return diskObservable;
  }
```

It didn't log anything at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be combining the status stream with the others, not creating two separate subscriptions - otherwise it doesn't really react to the network connectivity.

What you probably want to use is [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchMap(rx.functions.Func1)). Every time the network connectivity changes it can update which stream you're using.

In broad strokes, it'd go something like this:

```
connectivityObservable.switchMap(isConnected -> {
  if (isConnected) {
    return networkObservable;
  }
  return diskObservable;
}
```

(It looks like yours would be a bit more complex, I just want to lay out the general idea here.)